# horizontal list view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

Here is my code for `listView` and `Data Pager` ,

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="PageHorizon">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%">
                            <img src='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' alt="Single Image"  
                            width="64px" height="64px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="PageHorizon"  
     PageSize="3">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="True"   
            ShowNextPageButton="True" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowLastPageButton="True"   
            ShowPreviousPageButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

By this code , `listView` show images vertically , I want to show my images horizontally.
How can I change the orientation of `listView` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to show the images in a single row, you can just put them in the columns of a single row. Try rewriting the listview markup as follows (move `table`,`tr` markups into `LayoutTemplate`):

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="PageHorizon">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
        <tr>
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>  
            <td>
                <img src='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' alt="Single Image"  
                width="64px" height="64px" />
            </td>       
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I used this code once**

```
<asp:ListView ID="listview1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table  style="display: inline-block;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%#Bind('ImageURL') %>" CssClass="max75" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**give it a shot**

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

You can use a WrapPanel instead of the StackPanel.

Comment: This is asp.net, no WrapPanel :(