# .Net Listview with flow layout display horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I am working on my first Mobile Site using bootstrap. I am trying to create a Listview that is responsive, I made some research and I need to select Layout= Flow but my issue is that this layout flows from top to bottom (one column). I need to be able to display it from left to right up to 4 items, but I can't make it work.

code

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ProductsListView"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">

    <LayoutTemplate >
        <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" style="">
            <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
        </div>
        <div style="">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>


    <ItemTemplate>
        <span style="">ID:
        <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below displays the Listview item with layout = flow horizontally and it is responsive. I hope someone find it useful.

```
    <div style=" text-align: center;">

                <!-- start listview-->

                 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


                    <LayoutTemplate >
                    <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" >
                        <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                    </div>

                   </LayoutTemplate>


                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span>No data was returned.</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>

                    <table style="display: inline-block;" >

                     <tr >
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture") %>' Width="150px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="OrderOfferNameLabel" runat="server" 
                                        Text='<%# Eval("WHATEVER") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <span style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" 
                                        Text='<%# Eval("WHATEVER") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="44px" 
                                        style="height: 26px; width: 56px" Text="Button" Width="380px" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </table>


                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:ListView>

         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having the same problem as this user.

[horizontal list view in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433063/horizontal-list-view-in-asp-net)

The LayoutTemplate contains a block level element (the div). This means that the ItemTemplate will be wrapped in the div which will take up the full available width.

You should be able to just remove div from the LayoutTemplate, make it a span, or make it a table like in the Selected Answer of the post I linked from @mshsayem

> If you just want to show the images in a single row, you can just put
>   them in the columns of a single row. Try rewriting the listview markup
>   as follows (move `table`,`tr` markups into `LayoutTemplate`):
>
> ```
> <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="PageHorizon">
>   <LayoutTemplate>
>       <table>
>       <tr>
>          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
>       </tr>
>       </table>
>   </LayoutTemplate>
>   <ItemTemplate>  
>           <td>
>               <img src='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' alt="Single Image"  
>               width="64px" height="64px" />
>           </td>       
>   </ItemTemplate>
> </asp:ListView>
> ```

Comment: Hello Toni, thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I really appreciate it. I was testing your solution and it works great if you just want to display the items with layout "flow" horizontally. But in my case I needed to do so but also it has to be responsive which is not possible if the layout is a table. After many many hours I finally got it. I hope you have a great day!!